# Highlight only keywords inside a HTML tag and not when keyword forms part of another word

Tags: javascript, highlighting

[It works fine as shown in the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGsTd.png)

[The problem appears as seen in the second picture when the keyword is misspelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHhSz.png)

The problem is that I don't want the word to be highlighted when it forms part of another word. The problem can be seen in picture 2 where the keyword "online" is misspelled to "onlinee" and still the word "online" inside "**online**e" is highlighted. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

```js
var elementId = 'colouredText';
var text = 'online';

var eee = document.getElementById(elementId).outerHTML;

var tags = [];
var tagLocations = [];
var htmlTagRegEx = /<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/gi;


//Strip the tags from the elementHtml and keep track of them

var htmlTg = eee.match(htmlTagRegEx);
console.log(htmlTg);
for (var iu = 0; iu < htmlTg.length; iu++) {
  tagLocations[tagLocations.length] = eee.search(htmlTg[iu]);
  tags[tags.length] = htmlTg[iu];

  eee = eee.replace(htmlTg[iu], '');

}
var textLocationn = eee.search(text);



if (textLocationn) {
  //Add the highlight
  var highlightHTMLStart = "<span class='red'>";
  var highlightHTMLEnd = "</span>";
  eee = eee.replace(text, highlightHTMLStart + text + highlightHTMLEnd);

  //plug back in the HTML tags
  var textEndLocationn = textLocationn + text.length;

  for (var r = (tagLocations.length - 1); r >= 0; r--) {
    var locationn = tagLocations[r];
    if (locationn > textEndLocationn) {
      locationn += highlightHTMLStart.length + highlightHTMLEnd.length;
    } else if (locationn > textLocationn) {
      locationn += highlightHTMLStart.length;
    }
    eee = eee.substring(0, locationn) + tags[r] + eee.substring(locationn);
  }

}

//Update the innerHTML of the element
document.getElementById(elementId).outerHTML = eee;
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a green text, and here a red text</h1>

<ul id="colouredText">
  <li class="gold-text">around 560,000 onlinee tunes, available as free sheet music or midi sound files, at this site alone</li>
  <li>traditional music from medieval &amp; renaissance times up to the present day</li>
  <li>plenty of free software (Windows, Mac, Linux, mobile, ...) to transfer abc into scores or midi sound files</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```js
function search() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  if (!input.value) return;
  var element = document.querySelector('ul');
  var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + input.value + '\\b(?!>)', 'g');
  var match = element.innerHTML.match(regex);
  if (!match) return;
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="red">' + input.value + '</span>');
  input.value = match.length + ' matches';
  input.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input value="online">
<button onclick="search()">Mark</button>

<ul>
  <li>around 560,000 onlinee tunes, available as free sheet music or midi sound files, at this site alone</li>
  <li>online oonline online online</li>
  <li>traditional music from medieval &amp; renaissance times up to the present day</li>
  <li>plenty of free software (Windows, Mac, Linux, mobile, ...) to transfer abc into scores or midi sound files</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get the index of the matches? @Sam

Comment: Thank you so much @ Sam. That was really helpful.